# Calling postgreSQL stored procedure from Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc

When I try to call a stored procedure from `Java` - `Hibernate`. I got the below error.

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set:
```

and my Code

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select  commsrules.evalcommsrules(?::text,?::commsrules.t_commstype)");
                query.setString(0, in_query);
                query.setString(1, "TRIG");
        result = query.list();
```

and I got the below exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [:text, :commsrules.t_commstype] [select  commsrules.evalcommsrules(?::text,?::commsrules.t_commstype)]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:390)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.verifyParameters(SQLQueryImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:118)
```

please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's parsing `:text` and the other as a named parameter, even though you're trying to use positional parameters.

You could modify the query to use `CAST` instead of the `::` shorthand.